# PHPUnit & Group Use statements

Tags: php, phpunit, php-7

I am using PHPUnit to test my project running in PHP 7.0.2, but it seems to have issues with the group use statement. For example, this is an example file using a group use statement:

test.php

```
<?php
namespace MyFramework;

use \OtherFramework\{
    AwesomeClass,
    OtherAwesomeClass
};

// do ALL the things
```

When I run

```
php test.php
```

it works fine as expected. Now I was using PHPUnit 4.8.21, but when I tried

```
phpunit test.php
```

I got the error

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"' in test.php on line 4

Mind you, I am using other PHP 7 features such as the null coalesce operator (`??`) just fine in other tests, so I know that PHPUnit is running PHP 7. Next I tried upgrading to the preferred stable version (5.1.4) and got this response:

> This version of PHPUnit requires PHP 5.6; using the latest version of PHP is highly recommended.

And even my old tests without a group use statement won't run.

How can I run PHPUnit with PHP 7 and get the group use statements to work?

Comment: Are you sure that the PHP interpreter you use to run PHPUnit is actually PHP 7?

Comment: Apparently not. I'd aliased it but `/usr/bin/env php` was still set to 5.5. Thanks!